# How to get the indexes of sorted list of objects in java?

Tags: java, list, sorting, indexing

I have a list of java objects. I used the comparator to sort the list of objects based on a specific field. Now I need the indexes of elements when the list was not sorted. Can someone show some example please.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it :

- wrap your items in a class that contains an item and its index, sort the list, and you will have the original order recorded
- implement your own sort algorithm

Comment: I can create my own sort algo or can wrap into another class. But I want to know if any basic library function in java which supports this on lists. Because its a basic function on lists, I was expecting an efficient solution. Why a negative vote for this?

Comment: It is not that usual to need it, and you should know that Java has one of the most complete standard library, but it cannot do anything. In particular, it does not record the original order of the elements of a list that was sorted. Finally, I did not DV your post

Answer (score 0):

This can be done still in `O(N log(N))` (amortized) time if you're allowed extra space. Simply build a hashmap of the original indices of the items before sorting, then read them out again afterwards.

```
public static <T> int[] sortedIndices(List<T> lst, Comparator<T> comp){
    HashMap<T, Integer> indicesMap = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    for(T t : lst){
        indicesMap.put(t, i++);
    }
    ArrayList<T> cpy = new ArrayList<T>(lst);
    Collections.sort(cpy, comp);

    int[] indices = new int[cpy.size()];
    i = 0;
    for(T t : cpy){
        indices[i++] = indicesMap.get(t);
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Comment: What if the list contains duplicates ?

Comment: Hm. Well the problem kinda breaks in that scenario (if the sort wasn't stable, you can't know what the original indices were because you don't know which `3` went where). If that's the case then you must implement your algorithm. So I agree with your answer if duplicates are on the table.